# Opening a file in the browser, not working

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, hyperlink

I have a webpage with links to files on a network share but it is saying the file does not exist. Is there anything you can see wrong with my link?

file://client/M$/Documents/CDM%20Online%20Files/COM%20Certificates/Business%20Name%20COMCAS%20exp%2015.29.17.pdf

TIA

Comment: Have you tired adding an extra slash in front of file? So instead of file:// do file:///?

Comment: Thanks I tried with the extra slash and still cant find the file

Answer (score 0):

You Should try re checking your link then going through, or try another web browser. If this helps or doesnt please leave a comment and ill try my best to re look into it.

Comment: Thank you, still no luck with any of the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you question anyway try with this:

```
file:///client/M$/Documents/CDM%20Online%20Files/COM%20Certificates/Business%20Name%20COMCAS%20exp%2015.29.17.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks I tried with the extra slash and still cant find the file

Comment: Are you sure the path file is correct???? Try to search the file in your local network and then if you find it copy the path in you web page and change only the slash direction.